# I don't understand why my "not an answer" flag was declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I have in my flagging history a declined "Not an answer" flag that I'm having a hard time understanding. I hesitated to make a post because the flag is months old by now and because a single declined flag isn't the end of the world, but I just spent some time reading a lot of similar questions (and their answers) and I'm *still* curious exactly what happened with my flag.

The answer I flagged: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045151

The quick breakdown of what happened, from my perspective, is:

1. OP asked "how can I change the status bar color?"
2. Someone answered "use `setStatusBarBackgroundColor()`"
3. OP **posted a new answer** saying "Omg.... I did not know setStatusBarBackgroundColor() existed..." (verbatim; that's the whole post)
4. I flagged the post
5. OP edited their "OMG" answer to its current state

My understanding is that edits automatically "dispute" NAA flags, so the moderator must have declined my flag before the post was edited. (Please, correct me if I am wrong here.)

Having read other meta posts about "Not an answer" flags, I understand that this flag is meant for situations where the post really truly contains no kernel of an answer. In its current form, I can accept that what's left is just a really bad answer but an answer nonetheless. However, pre-edit it is blatantly a post that should have been a comment.

So, to finally make my question(s) crystal clear: Does

> Omg.... I did not know `setStatusBarBackgroundColor()` existed...

fall within "an attempt was made to answer the question" just because it includes the correct method to call (or for some other reason I can't see)?

Does it not matter that this (to my eyes) is *very obviously* something that should be a comment on the original (and accepted) answer?

Edit: I believe this question is not a duplicate because I'm not simply interested in whether or not a specific post is "not an answer;" I'm curious about how the poster's edits interact with my flag and how moderators would consider the before/after edit post.

Comment: This is not a dupe.  The question asks about the mechanics of the question being edited after the flag.

Comment: @StephenRauch Phew! It just scraped through the review. I intended to post a similar comment, but got distracted. +1 for backing me up.

Comment: Perhaps this should be its own question, but does "edit to explain how [the question is not a dupe]" mean that askers should add a paragraph saying "this is not a dupe because xyz", or does it mean that askers should improve the question such that a reader would be able to see that it is not a dupe?

Comment: @BenP. the thing to understand is that the question goes in to the review queue.  One hopes those of us in the review queue are doing our absolute best to research the circumstances around the question to weigh in on the review.  But... We are human, and sometimes don't do things perfectly.  So yes, anything you can do to help insure the reviewers are easily educated is a good idea.  Cheers.

Comment: If the post was edited after it was flagged, it really shouldn't be possible for the NAA flag to be declined any more (it should either be marked as helpful or disputed).

Comment: @Dukeling There are plenty of cases where people edit valid answers into still-valid answers. The flag is still as invalid as it ever was.

Comment: @Undo How often do mods check the revision history of a post in response to a NAA flag? My previous comment was based on the assumption that the answer is anything other than "at least always before declining it", in which case you can't really say with certainty that an answer was at no point not an answer, so it doesn't really make sense to potentially punish the flagger for a good-faith flag. Declining valid flags seems a lot worse than only disputing invalid one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edits don't do anything to NAA flags. They'll mark Very Low Quality flags as helpful, but for NAA there's normally no good reason to assume an edit will turn a non-answer into an answer.

The exception is in review, where a reviewer may opt to edit and thus *implicitly* dispute the flag. But this post wasn't edited from review (nor could an author review their own post anyway).

So, it just sat there until a moderator came along and declined it. Generally, I would consider this a positive outcome; even though you have a (now-ancient) declined flag, the answer itself was saved - possibly as a direct result of a comment left from review, which only happened because your flag put the post into review.

Comment: My interpretation of this is that the moderator declined the flag post-edit, and (after reading various NAA meta questions) I can see why they declined it. That said, I'm still curious if NAA would have been a "correct" flag if the user had never edited their post (in this specific situation). The confounding elements for me are (1) that the post includes the name of the correct method call and (2) that the post almost appeared to be accidentally made as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: To clarify/expand on my above comment: point (1) seems like a reason to decline the NAA flag and point (2) seems like a reason to accept it. It's this conflict that makes things unclear to me; I'm not sure which to weigh more heavily. Though, to be quite honest, if I hadn't read a bunch of meta posts about NAA I would lean massively in favor of point (2) being the winner... it seems like the "right" times to use NAA are much narrower than I would have guessed.

Comment: It's interesting that the review was invalidated 5min 56sec after the edit. The only thing I can think of that would make sense of this would be if there was *also* a VLQ flag on the answer, and *that* triggered the invalidation, whilst the NAA flag continued on its merry way to the moderator review queue. (Or do the flags appear immediately in the mod review queue?) Unless, of course, the timing was such that a moderator happened to work the fresh, just over an hour old, flag five minutes after the edit. To me, this would seem to have been unlikely. cc @BenP.

Comment: Why do edits mark VLQ flags as helpful? I thought VLQ was only for garbage that can't be improved and has to be deleted right away?

Comment: Ancient reasons, @Robert; that behavior predates review, and partially fulfilled the need for a "flag to edit" path at one time.

Comment: This is one of those "estimating probability is hard" situations, @robinCTS: the chances of a specific moderator seeing a specific flag on a specific post 5 minutes post-edit are small (though depending on the moderator probably greater than you'd think if they happen to like watching active questions, since editing bumps...); the chances of some moderator seeing some flagged answer 5 minutes after some edit are much greater.

Comment: The flag would've very likely been validated, @Ben. The answer *still* isn't great, but it looks like an answer; prior to the edit, it definitely wasn't an answer.

Comment: Yes, I realised, after posting, that the probability was probably (much?) higher than I originally thought. I've noticed that there is up to a couple of minutes delay between editing a VLQ flagged answer *outside* the queue, and when it gets invalidated. Six minutes is longer than I've ever seen, so that should have tipped the odds in favour of a moderator having invalidated it.

Comment: I think SO mods tend to want to review NAA flags quickly. I've seen them even try to change the official guidance on MSE to ask users to cast custom flags if it's not immediately clear from a quick glance that something's a non-answer.

Comment: @gparyani That *is* the guidance: official or not, you're going to have a better time explaining what's going on in a custom flag than an NAA flag. You have to understand just how many completely bogus NAA flags come in, make it through review, and then we have to sift through them. It's a lot - throwing your reasoning in a quick 'other' flag is much preferable to putting a bogus-looking flag in a pile of actually-bogus flags. For everyone involved.

Comment: @Undo For the record: another SO mod edited this into the MSE FAQ about the NAA flag, and it was reverted. We've had a user [complain about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300740) there: "On some sites (including SO), the moderators established a policy that posts should only be flagged as NAA if they can been recognized as such without looking at the question or comments; otherwise a custom flag should be raised. This is problematic as it contradicts the flag description..."

Comment: That's fine - usually, the system works fine, and usually people don't care much about declined flags. For the intersection of people who flag borderline things and people who care about flags, saying "doing this helps the right thing get done" is perfectly reasonable. No one ever said we *will* decline non-obvious NAA flags, just that it's more likely than it would be with a custom flag.

Answer (score 5):

This was my decline from a *loooong* time ago; Shog's answer is factually correct. I can't speculate on what I was thinking at the time.

At some point, I figured out that the "edit came in after flag" scenario is common and causes these discussions. I wrote [a (very ugly) script](https://github.com/Undo1/Undo-Userscripts/blob/master/flagtimingwarning.user.js) that does this:

[image]

In this case, it was either not running, broken, or ignored - but it's pretty useful for preventing these cases.