# Edits should not mark Very Low Quality (VLQ) flags as Helpful

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags, low-quality-posts

In a comment on [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364981/6471538) answer, I asked why edits mark VLQ flags as *Helpful*. @Shog9 ♦ replied:

> Ancient reasons, @Robert; that behavior predates review, and partially fulfilled the need for a "flag to edit" path at one time.

On Meta.SE, @JeffAtwood [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/336163) that,

> VLQ means the flagger thinks this post is beyond saving -- no amount of editing or polishing will turn this particular turd into gold. It is a call for a pooper-scooper. To clarify this, we are making the language a bit stronger:....
>
> Essentially this is synonymous with flag for removal. Both for the post and implicitly for the user who created that post … if they accrue enough of them....
>
> Whereas a downvote means "maybe this user is just having a bad day", a flag for low quality means this post, and possibly this user, are totally stinking up the joint and need to be ejected from the premises ASAP.

@Shog9 ♦ themselves [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764) that (regarding questions):

> **Use VLQ for obvious, unarguable *garbage*.**
>
> Regardless of whether or not it ends up in /review or the mod queue (and most of the time, it'll end up in both at least for a little while...) VLQ flags on questions that should be closed just create unnecessary overhead - someone else has to spend more time thinking about why the question needs to be closed because you didn't specify.

Edits on a post should not mark VLQ flags as *Helpful*. If the current VLQ "regime" now is centered on the idea that flagging VLQ is saying that the farmer ought to shoot the horse now right there in the ditch to put it out of its misery, it makes no sense to reward such flaggers when someone slaps a bandage on the horse or buys it a ticket to rehab. If the horse can be saved with a bandage or a trip to rehab, the person who said to shoot the horse right away needs *a talking to*.

If anything, an edit should *Dispute* VLQ flags, as it is an indication that another user likely thought that the post *could* be saved, which is contrary to the idea of VLQ as a "delete this crap right now" flag.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with this post.  But: "*VLQ is saying that the farmer ought to shoot the horse now*" is so awesome, I am up-voting anyways.

Comment: My memory is fading... See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed

Comment: "the person who said to shoot the horse right away needs a talking to" Either that or the edit didn't actually meaningfully fix the post.  Both happen a lot.  So either it makes sense to dispute the flag or the flag is still correct and shouldn't be completed *at all*.

Comment: We should also consider what happens to link-only answers ... as per the current guidance, (I believe) answers that just say "go here for the answer!" should be sent to VLQ and deleted. However, if the author edits it after getting comments to make a real answer, then it is no longer VLQ. In this case, both the flagger and the editor (the answerer) were doing the correct thing, so nobody "needs a talking to."

Comment: I don't see the point of your FR, as written. Why should we care about the difference between having the flag marked helpful vs. disputed just by an edit. For an edit by the OP, the post could have been changed into *anything*, even something that's quite good. There's no way for the system to know, without further input, if what you flagged was actually garbage, or not. To me the issue is that the flag is automatically dismissed *at all* just via any edit. IMO, the flag should not be dismissed and the post should continue to be reviewed, because too often such edits don't resolve the problem.

Comment: I'd agree that if a post ai edited after the flag was raised should be taken into account for the final disposition of the flag, but only *after* the post has completed a set of reviews in the appropriate review queue or been reviewed by a moderator. Ideally, flag disposition would reflect what people thought of the post as it was at the time the flag was raised, but reviewers and moderators should review the post in it's current state. Thus, if edited, the disposition should end up as disputed, if reviewers/mod think the post is OK now (with option for mod to specifically choose declined).

Answer (score 8):

As a flagger I believe it is the right thing that edits mark it helpful.

When I see an unintelligible text in Klingon language or a senseless placeholder blurb written by usual [fastest-gun](/questions/tagged/fastest-gun) abuser I would want to flag what I see and go on with a better things to do.

Last thing I would need in cases like that is to have to keep an eye on this garbage for just in case if it is somehow changed.

I don't care whether such an edit indicates that author improved after being scared by votes down and angry comments, or that post was seen by someone else who knows Klingon.

I feel like I have a right not to care about that something like that could happen. If the post was unsalvageable at the time I saw it, that's all I need. Otherwise I see no point in flagging at all.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion, but not what I interpret your actual concern to be. You appear to be looking at this only from the point of view. That concern is that your flag might be marked as declined, if the post is edited and reviewers or a moderator see the edited version and think your flag was baseless. While this is certainly something that is of concern from the point of view of the person flagging, I don't feel that optimizing *only* for that case is the appropriate course.

Comment: I feel the primary issue is getting bad content off the site w/o the need to have it reflagged. IMO, there are ways to address both concerns. One possibility: An edit doesn't mark the flag as helpful, but A) directly informs the moderator reviewing that it's been edited and provides them a way to easily view the content at the time the flag was raised (so they can mark the flag based on the content at that time), and B) flags resolved through review queue as OK after being edited results in the flag being disputed (which is a resolution we're not supposed to be concerned about).

Comment: @Makyen my point is, if you change cases like I described to non-helpful, people will just stop flagging. Nobody is willing to help if it is treated unfairly