# What is the impact of flag declined? Is it possible to ask moderator for clarification?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam, rude-or-abusive

I am still a bit confused about the workings of flagging stuff and moderators accepting/declining them.

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432965/c-how-to-give-multidimensional-array-to-function) as "In need of moderator intervention" and added a comment to the flag saying "contains spam". It wasn't a big deal, but I just want to take it as an example trying to get some clarification. The "spam" wasn't really rude language, but close to, on the other hand I felt that flagging it would be more appropriate than just editing myself. Shortly after I flagged it, it was edited by a third user, removing the nonsense spam part.

My flag was declined because "moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". Does this refer to the question in the state as the moderator found it? Is the history not considered during the moderator review?

To me "declined, found no evidence" sounds quite negative. Was my flag really that misplaced? Is there any way I could ask the moderator why they declined the flag? Does it have any negative impact on me when a flag gets declined? Should I have edited the question without flagging it?

Sorry for many questions, but I usually think twice before flagging something and often I don't understand why it gets declined, so other than not flagging I wouldn't know how to improve my flagging. Maybe I am just overthinking the whole thing and there isn't anything negative about flags getting declined and I should just flag what I think isn't OK and let the moderators sort it out?

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/175248

Comment: Executive summary:  this wasn't spam, it shouldn't have been flagged for spam.  If you felt like the question was poor, downvoting it or voting to close was enough.

Comment: @Makoto hm it wasnt really about the quality of the question itself, it did contain a line that was completely unrelated to the question saying: "bugadassdásde java is betta than c++ why is this so fkin retardte sdasd"... this isnt spam?

Comment: @Makoto also i didnt flag it as spam. I flagged it as "in need of moderator invention" and didnt find a better word for what was wrong than "spam"

Comment: @user463035818 No, that's not spam.

Comment: @user463035818:  Nope, still not spam.  Smells like frustration and is a thing that is *trivial* to edit out.

Comment: The more atrocious the question, the less help you need from a moderator to get it closed.  Why experienced SO users are editing this crap is however much harder to divine.  Reactivating it repeatedly does get it more downvotes, I guess.

Comment: @HansPassant do i understand you correctly that in your opinion the question should not have been edited to be easier closable?

Comment: It is my opinion that constantly re-activating dreadful questions ruins the fun for everybody.  Worse than spam, spam is easy to get rid of.

Comment: As for its impact on you, all it does is subtract one from your helpful flags count (which determines how many flags per day you get).  Nothing to worry about unless you're getting a lot of declined flags.

Answer (score 19):

Spam is inappropriate advertising or promotion of a product.  Using a term you think is offensive is not spam.

If a post actually *was* spam (this is not) then you should be using the spam flag, not a custom moderator flag.

If you think that a post contains offensive or abusive content, you should be flagging it as rude or abusive, not using a custom moderator flag.

But in a case like this where it's just an irrelevant line in an otherwise fine post, you should just be editing the post, not flag it (unless the user is editing it back in, then it'd merit a flag).

Comment: just to clarify: the question wasnt so much about wether this particular case is spam or not or what would have been the better flag, but more about what ways do I have to know why my flag was declined, if for the evaluation of the flag only the current state or also the edit history is of any relevance, and if in general editing should be prefered to flagging. Nevermind I got valuable input from comments and your answer

Comment: @user463035818 When you flag a post as spam, and it's not spam, your flag should be declined, because the post isn't spam, so you shouldn't do anything about the declined flag.  If there is some other problem that merits action, then you can take that action.  Some problems merit flags, others merit editing.  This problem doesn't require a flag.

Comment: this particular case was just an example. I have many declined flags where I am not 100% sure why they were declined. Its not a big problem for me, I just wonder how I can improve my flagging. Is there some action I can take in a case where I think it was wrongly declined and would like to get some clarification? I guess posting here is an option but I am not aware of any other way

Comment: @user463035818 Start by reading through the help center and FAQ entries on the issues in question, and search for meta for questions related to the problem you're trying to deal with.  For a case like this one that would have answered your concerns without requiring anyone else's time.  You can ask a moderator in chat, but posting on meta is fine if you don't understand how to properly address a situation or don't understand why a given flag was declined, after having done your research first into said issue.

Comment: ok, thanks for the input. My conclusion is to just flag more until I get the hang of it, and next time better consult the help center in case I am not sure what flag to use ;)

Comment: there is one point that remains a bit unclear to me (also after browsing the help). Lets suppose the question did contain spam and is salvaged by an edit of a third user. Would the flag be declined due to "no evidence", or is the edit history also considered by the mod? Dont worry, I am not trying to insist on anything, just trying to understand the details and I can image seeing something rude-or-offensive that I would wish to be removed also from the edit history

Comment: @user463035818 Mods don't see post revisions, unless they're using [userscripts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365091/563532) or clicking through to the post. But.. It's *very* unlikely that an actual spam post can be edited into something worthwhile. If it contains a spammy link in an otherwise good post, it's sufficient to merely edit it out (and warn the OP - assume good intentions), rather than raising a flag. If a post *looks* legitimate at first glance, but is actually nothing more than a spam post, you can use a custom flag to explain the situation.